# Inconsistent colors in Excel/PowerPoint/Word Charts

Tags: excel, charts, colors

I have two scatter plots, representing the same things, but for two different scenarios. They were created in the same Excel workbook, on different sheets, and I have the same color schemes applied to them. However, the colors don't line up between the charts. I have 6 charts total, and 4 start with the dark color and the other 2 start with a lighter color.

[image: Chart 1 - first color is very dark]

## Chart 1 - first color is very dark

[image: Chart 2 - first color is lighter]

## Chart 2 - first color is lighter

I haven't been able to find anyone else who's run into the same problem. This issue occurs when I copy the charts into PowerPoint and Word as well. This is pretty annoying because I want to keep the colors consistent throughout my charts.

*EDIT* I can copy the chart with the colors I want and then just edit the data, so the charts are all consistent. Still not sure how they ended up different colors, though.

Comment: You may need [tag:vba] to really fix the colour used for the graphs... hope someone has a better idea.

Answer (score 4):

I've run into this issue in the past.  I've looked around and found the following suggestions.

After copying the chart from Excel, when you're in either Powerpoint or Word, click on the downward arrow for "paste", then try to do **any one** of the following:

- 'paste special' then 'paste link'; or
- 'paste options' then 'keep source formatting'; or
- 'paste options' then paste as 'picture'.

The last one should definitely work, since you're pasting a static photo. That is, it will be uniform regardless of the program because it's based on the calibration setting of your monitor.

Comment: That isn't the problem. These are the original charts from Excel. They don't seem to be using the same order of colors - one starts at dark orange, the other starts at lighter orange.

Comment: Okay. So when you say "color scheme", do you mean one of the default color schemes for charts, or are you manually setting the colors?